# Can I just buy a Landscape server license?

Tags: landscape

I want to purchase Landscape, but I have yet to get my questions answered. I have about 400 Ubuntu 12.04 Laptops and 1 Ubuntu 12.04 Server.  Do I have to purchase a Landscape client licence for each of the 400 Laptops, or can I just buy 1 Server Licence to control all 400 Laptops?

Any help help would be great.

Answer (score 5):

Landscape is part of Ubuntu Advantage, which is a package that includes support for Ubuntu and a Landscape registration for the supported system.

In a SAAS configuration, you would purchase 400 Desktop UA subscriptions, and use Canonical's default Landscape.canonical.com server.  If you prefer to have the service on premise, you will need to add 1 Landscape Dedicated Server license to have a local instance of Landscape within your firewall perimeter.

As for the price, it changes significantly with volume.